# Problem with writing and showing Farsi(Persian) data in Excel (csv) file

Tags: visual-c++

I want to write some data in an excel file.
my program is here:

`

```
 using namespace std;

    ofstream MyExcelFile;
    MyExcelFile.open("test.csv");

    CString m_sName=L"ABBAS";
   int size_needed=WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, m_sName, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
   std::string utf8_string(size_needed, 0);
   WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, m_sName, -1, &utf8_string[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);
   MyExcelFile << utf8_string.c_str() << endl;

   MyExcelFile.close();

   LPCWSTR filename=L"test.csv";
   ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", filename, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

`
when I run my progrm, the test file open and I see:

```
     ` ABBAS`
```

Ok, but when I change m_sName to a Farsi(Persian) name like this:

`

```
    using namespace std;
    ofstream MyExcelFile;
    MyExcelFile.open("test.csv");

    CString m_sName=L"عباس";
   int size_needed=WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, m_sName, -1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
   std::string utf8_string(size_needed, 0);
   WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, m_sName, -1, &utf8_string[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);
   MyExcelFile << utf8_string.c_str() << endl;

    
   MyExcelFile.close();

   LPCWSTR filename=L"test.csv";
   ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", filename, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

`
after run, I see something like this:

```
`ةظ ط ط ي ظ`
```

in fact, the Farsi word cannot be written and shown correctly in file.
what is my mistake and what should I do to correct this?
thank to your help!

Comment: Try writing a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of the file, as in `MyExcelFile << "\xEF\xBB\xBF";` If I recall correctly, Excel assumes a CSV file without BOM to be encoded with the system-default codepage (aka `CP_ACP`)

Comment: I don't get it. would you please elaborate this?